# push project with git to TFS get stacked

Tags: git, tfs

I'm trying to push my project to TFS server using git and doing these 2 commands :

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL    
git push origin master
```

it show this:

```plain
$ git push -u origin --all
Counting objects: 7803, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7410/7410), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7803/7803), 73.56 MiB | 17.04 MiB/s, done.
Total 7803 (delta 1783), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

and it get stacked at that state for long time. and when i try to figure out the project on the server it was just empty.

I'm wondering what is exactly happened.

Comment: Stacked? Stuck, hung? Does it take a very long time? Does it error out?

Comment: yes it take a very long time and doesn't output any thing

Comment: It showing you have 7803 objects. Try to push only one or a few files/objects, could it be pushed successfully?